# Java Collection with 2 keys

Tags: java, collections, implementation

I want to implement a HashMap with a key with 2 components. Ex.

```
Pseudocode:

Key = <Component1, Component2>
CollName<Key, Val> coll = new CollName<Key, Val>;
```

How can I implement this in Java, considering speed and size of the Collection. Thanks :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a helper (composite key) class that holds your two keys

```
public class CompositeKey<... , ...> {
   ... component1;
   ... component2;

   // getter , setter, ...

   // equals

  // hashcode()
}
```

and then you can use it as key:

```
CompositeKey cKey = new CompositeKey(1,2);
Map x.put(cKey,val);
```

It is very important here to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` in a good fashion. Most IDEs can help you here. Important is for the hashCode that it returns a "unique" value in order to prevent hash collisions of the keys (i.e. returning a constant value is the worst case, as all values would end up in the same bucket). Many implementations of hashcode do something along

```
hashcode = component1.hashCode() + 37* component2.hashCode();
```

If you want more details, dig out any CS book that talks about hashing algorithms.

If you want to use that for persistence, also have a look at [this blog post](http://pilhuhn.blogspot.com/2006/08/how-to-outsmart-lazy-loading.html).

Comment: @Hieko: Inventive. Do you know of a source that explains helper classes as I'm not familiar with the concept.

Comment: A helper class isn't a special concept as such, it's just a normal class that wraps your two subobjects and treats them as one. See my example below for a more detailed code example.

Comment: @Hieko the key problem lies how you implement equals and hashcode correctly.

Comment: @suresh Exactly. I'll emphasis that in the answer.

Comment: @Hieko is it possible that  same implementation can be done with MulitMap from Guava Google Core Libraries.

Comment: Use a better name than `Helper`, please. This is obviously a `Pair`.

Comment: @Paŭlo changed -- while it is technically a Pair here, I want to stress the general concept of a composite key (it could also have 3 individual members .. )

Comment: *I just wanted to stress that `Helper` is a bad name (for about anything).*  If you have more elements, `Tuple` may be a good name - but if the elements have different types and you want them parametrized, you'll still need individual classes for each element number (pairs, triples, quadruples, quintuples, ...). (If all the elements have the same type, you could simply implement (or use a) `java.util.List` (preferably an immutable one).)

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly create a Map with two keys, however you can combine the two.

The simplest method is to serialize them to a string and combine them.

```
String key = obj1.toString() + "-" + obj2.toString();
myMap.put( key, myValue );
```

presuming the objects can easily be serialized to a string that would be unique.

If this is not the case, then creating a wrapper object is your best option. You would need to define an object that overrides the equals() and hashCode() method.

As a rough example

```
class CombinedKey{
    private MyClass object1; 
    private MyClass object2;

    public CombinedKey( MyClass object1, MyClass object2 ){
        this.object1 = object1;
        this.object2 = object2;
    }
    public int hashCode(){ 
        return object1.hashCode() + object2.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean equals( Object otherObject ){
        if( otherObject == null || otherObject.getObject1() == null ) return false;
        return object1.equals( otherObject.getObject1() ) && object2.equals( otherObject.getObject2();
    }

    public MyClass getObject1() { return object1; }
    public MyClass getObject2() { return object2; }

}
```

(You might also want to consider using Generics to define this class so it can be reused in other scenarios)

Usage:

```
Map<CombinedKey, Object> myMap = new HashMap<CombinedKey, Object>();
myMap.put( new CombinedKey(obj1, obj2), value );
```

Comment: Agree with your answer. Note the method equals() signature, it's not override from Object class.

Comment: Note that for a keypair (a,b) this implementation returns the same hashcode as for (b,a) which creates hash collisions, which may limit performance (somewhat).

Comment: That's a good point. It's probably not a problem for most implementations, but in some cases the developer may want to create a more robust implementation of hashCode()

Comment: @Zoomzoom: you should change your `equals` method to override Object.equals (this is, it should take an `Object` parameter and return `boolean`, not `Boolean`), otherwise it would be of no use in a HashMap.

Comment: @James P. Yes. It's for composite keys. I'm trying to use Java to upload data in a MySQL database :)

Comment: @user376290: I'm not sure but I think Hibernate/JPA can generate composite keys from annotations. I wouldn't use this framework solely for this reason though as it requires some learning.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't see a [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) answer yet, so thought I'd point it out: I'd use [Table](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html).

Answer (score 0):

It’s common usage of `HashMap`, the point is you have to define (override) **equals()** and **hashCode()** in class `Key` properly.

Answer (score 0):

A good alternative to using a `CompositKey`/`Pair`/`Tuple` is to use a `List`. `List` implementations already have a properly defined `equals()` and `hashCode()` and are easy to create using `Arrays.asList()`